# Faster alternative for large files: pdflib or princexml?

Tags: html, performance, pdf, pdflib, princexml

I've got some good experience with pdflib when it comes to speed of pdf-generation, even for large files.  I was excpecting the same speeds from princexml as for pdflib, as both run natively on my linux server (they're not just php-classes). When generating a 1 page pdf with text and graphics, I see a 4 second time lapse between begin and loading of the document in the log file? Is this normal? The conversion itself doesn't seem to be long...

```
Mon Apr 16 19:17:30 2012: ---- begin
Mon Apr 16 19:17:34 2012: Loading document...
Mon Apr 16 19:17:34 2012: Converting document...
Mon Apr 16 19:17:34 2012: finished: success
Mon Apr 16 19:17:34 2012: ---- end
```

Comment: The problem seems to have been due to trouble with the dynamic libraries. It resolved after fresh install using the .deb file, and there are currently no speed-issues. It's actually as quick as pdflib.

Answer (score 0):

Are there network connections involved in your setup? Is there DNS name resolution involved? If yes, try to use IP addresses instead of hostnames and try again...